# Setting particular type of attack with Sqlmap

Tags: security, sql-injection, sqlmap

Instead of testing all the possible attacks using sqlmap, is there any way to test a vulnerable server using a particular type of attack only? For example, I only want to attack a webserver with PostgreSQL stacked conditional-error blind queries. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Have you already read the advanced help using `-hh`?

Answer (score 8):

The `--dbms=DBMS` flag will force use of a particular back-end database system.

For PostgresSQL set this to

```
--dbms=PostgreSQL
```

The `--technique` flag will enable you to set the type of queries.

e.g.

```
--technique=B
```

`B` is the setting for boolean-based blind.

See [the usage](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage) guide for full details.